# Is there any solution for getting next row in Sheet7

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function Copy_data(){
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();    
   var ts  = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet7');     
  var nextrow = ts.getLastRow()+1;
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet6');
  var lastRow= ss.getLastRow();
  for(var i = 2; i<lastRow;i++){
var Date = ss.getRange(i,1).getValues();
var Product = ss.getRange(i,2).getValues();
    var URL = ss.getRange(i,7).getValues();
    if(URL = ss.getRange(i,7).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl()){
for (var j = 2; j<nextrow;j++){
 ts.getRange(j,1).setValues(Date);
 ts.getRange(j,2).setValues(Product);

      }}}}
```

My i loop is incrementing but j is not getting next row. i is putting value in row 2 of the Sheet7. It is just replacing value in second row. I did not getting result in the next row.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ki3VP8DhwGmo_9-UP3bIDTBhVMzHfnNdQgOM2NbiITc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This is the link I want to put data in Sheet7 from Sheet6  basis on Column G Values. My problem is that second loop putting all values in row 2. Sheet7 is not getting data in next row. I want to put all data in Sheet7 basis on condition.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, you want to copy rows, that the column "G" in "Sheet6" has a link, to "Sheet7". Is my understanding correct? Unfortunately, I cannot find your sample input and output situations in your provided sample Spreadsheet. I apologize for this. So, I cannot still understand your question. Especially, I cannot understand `on condition` of `I want to put all data in Sheet7 basis on condition.`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

From `Yes, you are correct. How can I do this?` for `you want to copy rows, that the column "G" in "Sheet6" has a link, to "Sheet7".`, in this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet6");
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet7");
  const values = srcSheet.getRange("A2:G" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(r => r[6]);
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the rows, that the column "G" in "Sheet6" has a link, are copied to "Sheet7".
- From your sample Spreadsheet, I thought that the above script will be able to be used for achieving your goal. But, if you want to check the hyperlink of the cell, how about the following sample script?

  ```js
  function sample() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet6");
    const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet7");
    const range = srcSheet.getRange("A2:G" + srcSheet.getLastRow());
    const srcValues = range.getValues();
    const idx = range.getRichTextValues().reduce((ar, r, i) => {
      if (r[6].getLinkUrl()) {
        ar.push(i);
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);
    const values = idx.map(i => srcValues[i]);
    if (values.length == 0) return;
    dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: @DME1 SSPL About `Thank you so much. This is very helpful for me. Thank you so much`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I don't find push button but I accepted your answer. This script is helpful but is not working on large data. It is giving The Javascript runtime exited unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses the syntax of the OP; it may be useful for those users who are using old-school methods.

There are four basic problems with the OP script:

- the `for` statement condition should be `i<lastRow+1`
- the second `for` statement (`for (var j = 2; j<nextrow;j++){`) is not required
- the row number for ranges on the "target" sheet is `nextrow`

  - the value of `nextrow` is incremented (`nextrow++`) at the end of each loop

The script is inefficient since is includes many `getValue` and `setValue` statements. But this is something that the OP can address.

---

**REPLACE**

```
for(var i = 2; i<lastRow;i++){
  var Date = ss.getRange(i,1).getValues();
  var Product = ss.getRange(i,2).getValues();
  var URL = ss.getRange(i,7).getValues();
  if(URL = ss.getRange(i,7).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl()){
    for (var j = 2; j<nextrow;j++){
      ts.getRange(j,1).setValues(Date);
       ts.getRange(j,2).setValues(Product);
    }
  }
}
```

---

**WITH**

```
for(var i = 2; i<lastRow+1;i++){
  var Date = ss.getRange(i,1).getValues();
  var Product = ss.getRange(i,2).getValues();
  var URL = ss.getRange(i,7).getValues();
  if(URL = ss.getRange(i,7).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl()){
    ts.getRange(nextrow,1).setValue(Date);
    ts.getRange(nextrow,2).setValue(Product);
    nextrow++
  }
}
```